# Typo3 - delete button deletes two records instead of one

Tags: typo3

Following problem with the delete button in that picture:

[image]

Our backend menu shows some input fields of table tx_extensionname_item.
The tables are configured via `$TCA` so that the delete button doesn't really
deletes a record but sets its deleted flag to "1".

But the same menu shows some fields from table tx_extensionname_details. 
After delete, the flag of this table is set to "1" too.

Is it possible to modify the delete function so it will only delete records from table _item instead of both tables?

Comment: Can you show the `TCA` configuration of the tables, at least the field configuration for the relation fields? I suspect you are using an inline field and have not set [`behaviour.enableCascadingDelete = 0`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Inline/Index.html#behaviour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Inline/Index.html#behaviour

> enableCascadingDelete (boolean) Enables the deletion of child records
>   along with their parent record. Defaults to TRUE.